# Problema al correr runserver - DJANGO

Tags: python, django

Estoy siguiendo un tutorial de Django y a la hora de crear el superusuario en Django y querer ejecutar runserver me salta el siguiente error:
Busque en varios foros, cambie la version de python y no encontre alguna solucion. Espero de su ayuda, gracias!
Quisiera poder identificar en donde esta el error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Diego\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line        
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Diego\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Diego\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Diego\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 61, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Diego\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Diego\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 96, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Users\Diego\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 103, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Diego\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 638, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Diego\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 623, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "C:\Users\Diego\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 328, in run
    autoreload_started.send(sender=self)
  File "C:\Users\Diego\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 182, in send
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "C:\Users\Diego\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 182, in <listcomp>
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "C:\Users\Diego\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\autoreload.py", line 44, in watch_for_template_changes
    for directory in get_template_directories():
  File "C:\Users\Diego\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\autoreload.py", line 21, in get_template_directories
    items.update(Path.cwd() / to_path(dir) for dir in backend.engine.dirs)
  File "C:\Users\Diego\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\autoreload.py", line 21, in <genexpr>
    items.update(Path.cwd() / to_path(dir) for dir in backend.engine.dirs)
  File "C:\Users\Diego\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\_os.py", line 58, in to_path
    raise TypeError('Invalid path type: %s' % type(value).__name__)
TypeError: Invalid path type: list
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Agrega el comando que usaste que te produjo este output. Tambien si es posible agrega la ruta desde el cual estás ejecutando el proyecto. Puede ser que tenga que ver con esto ultimo.

Comment: Hola, podrias por favor poner lo que tienes en settings en especial lo que tienes en la  variable de TEMPLATES